# Hive regex: Positive lookahead to match '&' or end of string

Tags: regex, hive

I would like to match text between two strings, although the last string/character might not aways be available.

String1: 'www.mywebsite.com/search/keyword=toys'

String2: 'www.mywebsite.com/search/keyword=toys&lnk=hp1'

Here I want to match the value in keyword= that is 'toys' and I am using

(?<=keyword=)(.*)(?=&|$)

Works for String1 but for String2 it matches everything after '&'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In regex, match either the end of the string or a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083308/in-regex-match-either-the-end-of-the-string-or-a-specific-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy. It takes everything it can, therefore stops at the end of the string (`$`) and not at the `&` character.
Change it to its non-greedy version - `.*?`

```
with t as
(
    select  explode
            (
                array
                (
                    'www.mywebsite.com/search/keyword=toys'
                   ,'www.mywebsite.com/search/keyword=toys&lnk=hp1'
                )
            ) as (val)
)
select  regexp_extract(val,'(?<=keyword=)(.*?)(?=&|$)',0)
from    t
;
```

---

```
+------+
| toys |
+------+
| toys |
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to bother with greediness when you need to match zero or more occurrences of any characters but a specific character (or set of characters). All you need is to get rid of the lookahead and the dot pattern and use `[^&]*` (or, if the value you expect should not be an empty string, `[^&]+`):

```
(?<=keyword=)[^&]+
```

Code:

```
select regexp_extract(val,'(?<=keyword=)[^&]+', 0) from t
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hDh7ET/2)

Note you do not even need a capturing group since the `0` argument instructs `regexp_extract` to retrieve the value of the *whole match*.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=keyword=)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `keyword=`
- `[^&]+` - any 1+ chars other than `&` (if you use `*` instead of `+`, it will match 0 or more occurrences).