# How do I use regex to match up to a pattern, if present, and otherwise to the end of the string?

Tags: regex

I am parsing the command line portion of a string from a log, which occasionally appears at the end of the string.

This question [In regex, match either the end of the string or a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12083308/10096858) does not help me, because when I try adding `|$` to the end of the non-capture group like this

```
(?:CommandLine|Process Command Line):\s?([\S\s]+)(?:CurrentDirectory|\s+Token|$)
```

it includes `CurrentDirectory` following the command line as part of the match, which I do not want.

The string could look like this:

```
string1 = 'OriginalFileName: PowerShell.EXE CommandLine: powershell -Enc QQBkAGQALQBUAHkAcABlACAALQBBAHMAcwBlAG0AYgBsAHkATgBhAG0AZQAgAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AUwBlAGMAdQByA CurrentDirectory: C:\Windows\system32\'
```

In this case I can extract the portion

```
'QQBkAGQALQBUAHkAcABlACAALQBBAHMAcwBlAG0AYgBsAHkATgBhAG0AZQAgAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AUwBlAGMAdQ`'
```

using this pattern

```
'(?:CommandLine|Process Command Line):\s?([\S\s]+)(?=CurrentDirectory|\s+Token)'
```

but this fails in cases like this that end with a `\n`:

```
string2 = 'CommandLine: powershell -Enc QQBkAGQALQBUAHkAcABlACAALQBBAHMAcwBlAG0AYgBsAHkATgBhAG0AZQAgAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AUwBlAGMAdQBHQAeQBzAG\n'
```

or like this, where the part I want to extract is at the end of the string:

```
string3 = 'CommandLine: powershell -Enc QQBkAGQALQBUAHkAcABlACAALQBBAHMAcwBlAG0AYgBsAHkATgBhAG0AZQAgAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AUwBlAGMAdQByAGkAdAB5ADsACgBmAHUAb'
```

How can I match up until `CurrentDirectory|\s+Token` if either one exists, but otherwise go to end of the string?

Here is an example of my pattern matching most of the command line portions of the string, but not the last one at the end of the string: [regex101.com/r/kETNpo/1](https://regex101.com/r/kETNpo/1)

Comment: Instead of a lookahead, use an optional group, and make `.+` non-greedy with `.+?`

Comment: @anubhava I had tried that (should've mentioned it) but it matched until the end of the string, even when 'CurrentDirectory' was present.

Comment: @Barmar what would that look like? I was using `([\S\s]+)` instead of `.+` for the capture group because sometimes there newlines in the part of the string I wanted to capture.

Comment: ok try: `(?:CommandLine|Process Command Line):\s?(.+?)(?=CurrentDirectory|\s+Token|$)`

Comment: @anubhava thanks for that, but still not matching. This is the pattern I am using https://regex101.com/r/kETNpo/1, which is matching 3/4 of the cases, but not the last one.

Comment: @saujosai: ok try this: `(?:CommandLine|Process Command Line):\s?([\S\s]+?)(?:CurrentDirectory|\s+Token|\Z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for all of your matches:

```bash
(?:CommandLine|Process Command Line):\s?([\S\s]+?)(?:\bCurrentDirectory|\s+Token|\Z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kETNpo/2)

Important changes from your original regex are:

- `[\S\s]+?`: To match this match non-greedy
- `(?:\bCurrentDirectory|\s+Token|\Z)`: Non-capturing group to match full word `CurrentDirectory` or `Token` after 1+ whitespaces or else match end of input.